# 2d laplacian computation in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I want to do a toy code computing the laplacian of the function f(x,y) = sin(pi (x+1)/2)*sin(pi (y+1)/2) for (x,y) in [-1,1]^2.

I have tried multiple methods:

- The first one works
- the second one has a bug when calculating u_xx
- the third one gives wrong results. I dont even know what is in the hess variable
- the fourth one is a try of the tf.hessians function that doesnt work.

If someone can shed some light, I would be indebted.

````
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pi = np.pi

# function that will be passed to autmoatic differentiation
@tf.function
def sol(X):
 x,y = X[:,0] , X[:,1]
 return tf.sin(pi*(x+1)/2)*tf.sin(pi*(y+1)/2)
@tf.function
def sol2(X,Y):
 return tf.sin(pi*(X+1)/2)*tf.sin(pi*(Y+1)/2)

# true laplacian for comparison
def f(X):
 x , y = X[:,0] , X[:,1]

 return -pi**2/2*tf.sin(pi*(x+1)/2)*tf.sin(pi*(y+1)/2)

def fgrid(X,Y):
 return -pi**2/2*tf.sin(pi*(X+1)/2)*tf.sin(pi*(Y+1)/2)

#######"MESH OVER THE SQUARE"
n = 500
x1 , x2 = -1 , 1
vec = tf.linspace(x1,x2,n)
xgrid,ygrid = tf.meshgrid(vec,vec)

xrow,yrow = tf.reshape(xgrid,(-1,1)),tf.reshape(ygrid,(-1,1))
Xdata = tf.Variable(tf.concat((xrow,yrow),axis=1))

#######COMPUTING LAPLACIAN
# FIRST WORKING METHOD
"""
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
 xx = tf.reshape(Xdata[:,0],(-1,1))
 yy = tf.reshape(Xdata[:,1],(-1,1))
 tape.watch(xx)
 tape.watch(yy)
 u = sol(tf.concat([xx,yy],axis=1))
 u_x = tape.gradient(u,xx)
 u_xx = tape.gradient(u_x,xx)
 
 u_y = tape.gradient(u,yy)
 u_yy = tape.gradient(u_y,yy)
lapl = (u_xx+u_yy)
del(tape)
#displaying results
plt.contourf(xgrid,ygrid,lapl.numpy().reshape(n,n))
#"""
# SECOND METHOD NOT WORKING : error in u_xx computation 
"""
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
 xx = tf.Variable(Xdata[:,0])
 yy = tf.Variable(Xdata[:,1])
 u = sol(Xdata)
 u_x = tape.gradient(u,xx)
 u_xx = tape.gradient(u_x,xx)

 u_y = tape.gradient(u,yy)
 u_yy = tape.gradient(u_y,yy)
lapl = u_xx + u_yy
del(tape)
#"""
#plt.contourf(xgrid,ygrid,lapl.numpy().reshape(n,n))

# THIRD METHOD NOT WORKING : wrong results
"""
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
 u = sol(Xdata)
 grads = tape.gradient(u,Xdata)
 hess = tape.gradient(grads,Xdata) # shape (-1,2)

lapl = hess[:,0] + hess[:,1]

del(tape)
plt.contourf(xgrid,ygrid,lapl.numpy().reshape(n,n))
#"""

# FOURTH METHOD NOT WORKING : tf.hessians (use Gradient.tape instead) or 'GradientTape' object has no attribute 'hessians'
"""
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
 u = sol(Xdata)
 hess = tape.hessians(u,Xdata)

lapl = hess[:,0] + hess[:,1]
plt.contourf(xgrid,ygrid,lapl.numpy().reshape(n,n))
#"""
# second try with tf.hessians
#"""
hess = tf.hessians(sol(Xdata),Xdata) #tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.
#""" ```
````